In CMake, how to check if the file IS_NEWER_THAN strictly?
You might be familiar with cmake IS_NEWER_THAN.
if(${FILE1} IS_NEWER_THAN ${FILE2})

It returns true if:

File1 is newer than files
If file1 does not exist
If file2 does not exist.
File1 and file2 have the same timestamp

I wanted to know how to actually check that file1 newer than file2.  I did not want to trigger the if statement if they were the same timestamp.  But how to do that?

Can you not just if(NOT(${FILE2} IS_NEWER_THAN ${FILE1}))?
Related issue ticket: if(... IS_NEWER_THAN ...) is misleading and easy to misuse #21849.

My solution was to make a bash call:
execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "[ '${_file1}' -nt '${_file2}' && echo 'error'" OUTPUT_VARIABLE ret)
if(ret AND NOT ret EQUAL 0)


I don't find it a particularly great assumption that the user has bash on their system, or a great practice of spawning a shell... also creating just another opening for bad things to happen from potential wrong assumptions about the file names being actual file names.
